# Can IntelliJ Idea work with maven-failsafe-plugin tests?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

According to the `maven-failsafe-plugin`'s convention. integration tests need to be placed under `src/it`. This is all fine and dandy, but IntelliJ Idea doesn't:

- Treat the code in `src/it` as test code
- Let you run these tests through the UI

I have 2017.1.3 and I have also installed the Maven Test Support Plugin. Doesn't Idea support this kind of separation?

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91609.

Comment: Serge, so does this mean that it's not supported even with that plugin? Do you guys have any plans to look into this? Idea should be able to recognize test classes (hints: file name ends with`*Test`, `*TestIT`, or classes that have `@Test` in them) and it should be possible to run them... Is there any workaround, or do you have an estimate of when this would be implemented?

Comment: Just mark the test source roots manually and trigger the option to keep them, it's mentioned in the issue comments. Run tests by pattern, there is a popular answer here from me with the sample regex.

Comment: Where's this option to keep them upon re-import? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: This option [is here](http://i.imgur.com/yUEVotg.png).